# How can i deploy an function-app in azure from a remote git using terraform?

Tags: git, azure, deployment, terraform, azure-function-app

When running my terraform deployment, i want to pull a function app from a remote git server. 
In the same terraform template i deploy a docker image from a private registry with no problem. I just can't find how to deploy the function app from a remote git server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is no property for Azure function to set the GitHub repository in Terraform. You can see all properties support in [Azure Function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/function_app.html#argument-reference).

But you can take the use of Azure CLI and provisioner "local-exec" in Terraform. Take a look at the steps in [Terraform module for Azure FunctionApp](https://github.com/anoff/terraform-azurerm-functionapp) and use the Azure CLI command [`az functionapp deployment source config`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/deployment/source?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-deployment-source-config) instead of the CLI command inside the code. Then the provisioner "local-exec" will look like below:

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "${var.git_enabled ? join("", list("az functionapp deployment source config --ids ", azurerm_function_app.funcapp.id), " --repo-url github_URI", " --branch master --manual-integration") : "true"}"
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had not any success with your suggested string. But your hint to the documentation already helped. I needed to add "configure".
"az functionapp deployment source configure --ids " ... The connection with the git server seems to work, but there is no http-trigger set. So something still seems to be wrong but heading the right direction

Comment: So i guess the problem now is, that my app is in Java and my deployment does not account for that. If you add the missing "config" in your solution i accept it as resolved.

Comment: @WalterGill You can follow the steps in [Function in Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-java-maven) to set your own triggers.

Comment: @WalterGill Are you sure your application works fine locally?

Comment: @CharelsXu My function even runs fine in Azure after deploying it from vs-code. I'm pretty sure my terraform template for the function-app is wrong somewhere.

Comment: So, when i do the deployment from GIT it just copies my source code to te www-root. This means the app is not build. Is there a way to alter the exec-command to pull build and then deploy the app?